# Run Length Encoding (Integers)

Tags: c++, encoding, integer, run-length-encoding

In class we were talking about RLE and our Professor showed us the following code. I tried to understand it, but I don't quite get it. So I'd be very thankful if someone could explain to me how RLE on this example works.
I do understand how to achieve the data compression but I do not understand the implemantation of the program. In the comments you will find my questions.

```
// Example implementation of a simple variant of // run-length encoding and  decoding of a byte sequence

#include <iostream> 
#include <cassert>

// PRE: 0 <= value <= 255 
// POST: returns true if value is first byte of a tuple, otherwise false 

bool is_tuple_start(const unsigned int value) 
{ 
    assert(0 <= value && value <= 255);
    return value >= 128; //Why is it: value>=128 for first Byte of tuple?
}

// PRE: 1 <= runlength <= 127 //Why must runlength be in this range?
// POST: returns encoded runlength byte 

unsigned int make_tuple_start(const unsigned int run_length) 
{ 
    assert(1 <= run_length && run_length <= 127);
    return run_length + 128; //Why do I add 128?
}

// PRE: n/a 
// POST: returns true if value equals the maximal run-length 

bool is_max_runlength(const unsigned int value)  
{
    return value == 127; //same question: why is max. range 127?
}

// PRE: 128 <= value <= 255 //Why this range for value?
// POST: returns runlength of tuple 

unsigned int get_runlength(const unsigned int value) 
{ 
    assert(128 <= value && value <= 255);
    return value - 128; //Why -128?
}

// PRE: n/a 
// POST: outputs value and adds a newline 

void out_byte(const unsigned int value) 
{ 
    std::cout << value << "\n"; 
}

// PRE: 1 <= runlength <= 127 and 0 <= value <= 255 
// POST: outputs run length encoded bytes of tuple 

void output(const unsigned int run_length, const unsigned int value) 
{ 
    assert(1 <= run_length && run_length <= 127); 
    assert(0 <= value && value <= 255); //Why is value now between 0 and 255?

    if (run_length == 1 && !is_tuple_start(value)) 
        { 
            out_byte(value); 
        } 
    else 
        { 
            out_byte(make_tuple_start(run_length)); 
            out_byte(value); 
        }
}

// PRE: n/a 
// POST: returns true if 0 <= value <= 255, otherwise false 

bool is_byte(const int value) 
{ 
    return 0 <= value && value <= 255; 
}

// PRE: n/a 
// POST: outputs error if value does not indicate end of sequence 

void check_end_of_sequence(const int value) 
{ 
    if (value != -1) 
        { 
            std::cout << "error\n"; 
        } 
}

// PRE: n/a 
// POST: reads byte sequence and outputs encoded bytes 

void encode() 
{ 
    std::cout << "--- encoding: enter byte sequence, terminate with -1\n";
    int value;

    std::cin >> value;

    if (is_byte(value)) 
        { 
            int prev_value = value; //When/Where does value Change?
            unsigned int run_length = 1;

            while(true) 
                {
                    // read next byte, stop if invalid or end of sequence 

                    std::cin >> value; 
                    if (!is_byte(value)) 
                        { break; }

                    // output if value has changed or maximal runlength is reached 
                    // otherwise increase length of current run 

                    if (value != prev_value || is_max_runlength(run_length)) 
                        { 
                            output(run_length, prev_value); 
                            run_length = 1; 
                            prev_value = value; 
                        } 
                    else { ++run_length; }
                }
            output(run_length, prev_value);
        }

    // output "error" if sequence terminated incorrectly 

    check_end_of_sequence(value);
}

// PRE: n/a 
// POST: reads byte sequence and outputs decoded bytes 

void decode() 
{ 
    std::cout << "--- decoding: enter byte sequence, terminate with -1\n";
    int value; 

    while(true) {

        // read next byte, stop if invalid or end of sequence 

        std::cin >> value; //is value only a Byte? Or the whole sequence?

        if (!is_byte(value)) 
            { break; }

        // if this is a tuple output read next byte, otherwise output directly 

        if (is_tuple_start(value)) 
            {
                unsigned int run_length = get_runlength(value);

                // next must be a valid byte, otherwise this is an error 
                std::cin >> value; 

                if (!is_byte(value)) 
                    { 
                        value = 0; 
                        // trigger error in case value = -1 
                        break; 
                    }

                // output uncompressed tuple 

                for(int i = 0; i < run_length; ++i) 
                    { 
                        out_byte(value); 
                    }
            } 

        else { out_byte(value); }
    }

    // output "error" if sequence terminated incorrectly 

    check_end_of_sequence(value);
}


int main(const int argc, const char* argv[]) 
{ 
    std::cout << "--- select mode: 0 = encode / 1 = decode\n"; 

    unsigned int mode; 
    std::cin >> mode;

    if (mode == 0) 
        { 
            encode(); 
        } 
    else if (mode == 1) 
        { 
            decode();
        } 
    else 
        { 
            std::cout << "--- unknown mode, must be 0 (encode) or 1 (decode)\n"; 
        }
}
```

I hope to get answers to my questions and that the code is readable, which was basically copy+paste from my lecture notes.

Comment: An example Input was given as well: Encode: 0 42 42 85 85 85 85 172 172 172 13 13 42 -1 and Decode: 1 2 42 4 85 3 172 2 13 1 42 -1

Comment: Add that to the question, not a comment.

Answer (score 4):

The way this encoding works is that a sequence of repeating values is stored as:

```
<length> <value>
```

while a non-repeating value is stored simply as:

```
<value>
```

But when you see a number in the encoded sequence, how do you know if it's the length part of the first format, or just a single, non-repeating value? It does this by using the rule that we add 128 to the length before encoding it. So any number > 128 is the `<length>` byte that starts the first format.

But what if the value of a non-repeated item was higher than 128? The solution for this is to use the first format for large values, treating it as a repeated value with `runlength = 1`.

This should answer most of your questions, which are about all the range additions and subtractions.

*Why must runlength be in this range?*

We're storing everything as bytes from 0 to 255. If the length were >127, then when we add 128 to it we'd get a number >255, which doesn't fit in a byte.

*is value only a Byte? Or the whole sequence?*

The declaration is `int value;`, so it's just a single number. Each time it does `cin >> value;` it gets the next byte in the sequence.

*Why is value now between 0 and 255?*

Value is always allowed to be a whole byte, only lengths are limited to 127 because we add 128 to them. See the explanation above that high values are always encoded as a tuple with the length first.

Comment: Thanks so much for this enlightening answer! Just one more question, do u know that why `value > 127` indicates `is_tuple_start `? in my understanding, the encoded normal characters can also be larger than 127, so it does not necessary mean it's the start of the tuple?

Comment: That's how it tells whether the byte is a length or data byte.

Comment: but I thought from 128-256 are the Extended ASCII characters, which could also be in the data bytes? Or do we just assume these are not included in the data?

Comment: You can't do them as a single byte. If you want the byte `200`, you have to represent it as  `129 200`: length 1, byte value 200. You can only represent values below 128 as a single byte.

Comment: Otherwise, there's no way to tell whether it's a length or data.

Comment: and that would mean that it's possible for these extended ascii chars to be represented in more bytes after compression I guess? since now we must save a byte for length

Comment: yes. RLE only provides good compression if you have lots of repeated bytes.

Comment: Note also that traditional RLE uses a length before everything: `length1 byte1 length2 byte2 ...`. The approach here is able to use 1 byte whenever length = 1 and byte < 128, so it's actually an improvement.

Comment: I see, thanks for all these nice detailed explanations!